# Is it possible to calculate distance if non-constant acceleration is unknown?

Tags: kinematics

I know that the distance travelled in non constant acceleration is $d=\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$, but is it possible to calculate the distance without knowing the value of $f(x)$?

Comment: What does $f(x)$ mean? Distance is the time integral of velocity, which is itself the time integral of acceleration.

Comment: Please tell what is known. This is like you don't have anything and want distance covered.Think,how is it possible?

Comment: This question is very unclear and potentially too localized too.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

You atleast need something known viz jerk,acceleration, velocity, displacement etc.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the expression above, I realized that $x$ is time and $f(x)$ is a time dependent velocity. Am I right? The function $f(x)$ is not the only quantity defining the distance. This quantity as well as any other parameters of the dynamical system can be derived if you know the Hamiltonian or Lagrangian (probably with explicit time dependence in your case) and, as has been mentioned by `userØØ7`, initial conditions.